# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to LittleEndian ByteOrder

Tags: c#, binaryreader

I have a problem with my function for loading RAW images. I don't understand the reason for the error. It shows me this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Digital_Native_Image.DNI_Image.Byteorder'

```
public void load_DNI(string ficsrc)
{
    FileStream FS = null;
    BinaryReader BR = null;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    DNI_Image.Datatype dataformat = Datatype.SNG;
    DNI_Image.Byteorder byteformat = Byteorder.LittleEndian;

    FS = new FileStream(ficsrc, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
    BR = new BinaryReader(FS);

    dataformat = BR.ReadInt32();
    byteformat = BR.ReadInt32();
    width = BR.ReadInt32();
    height = BR.ReadInt32();

    // fermeture des fichiers
    if ((BR != null))
        BR.Close();
    if ((FS != null))
        FS.Dispose();

    // chargement de l'_image
    ReadImage(ficsrc, width, height, dataformat, byteformat);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int`'s cannot be implicitly converted to `enum`'s. You need to add explicit casts here:

```
dataformat = (Datatype.SNG)BR.ReadInt32();
byteformat = (Byteorder)BR.ReadInt32();
```

Read [Casting and Type Conversions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) for more information.

However, note that the `if (BR != null)` check is not necessary, and this is really not the right way to handle [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) objects. I'd suggest you rewrite this code to use [`using` blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). This will ensure that `FS` and `BR` get disposed properly:

```
int width;
int height;
Datatype dataformat;
Byteorder byteformat;

using (var FS = FileStream(ficsrc, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
using (var BR = new BinaryReader(FS))
{

    dataformat = (Datatype.SNG)BR.ReadInt32();
    byteformat = (Byteorder.LittleEndian)BR.ReadInt32();
    width = BR.ReadInt32();
    height = BR.ReadInt32();
}

// chargement de l'_image
ReadImage(ficsrc, width, height, dataformat, byteformat);
```

But it also seems like you can improve this more by refactoring the `ReadImage` method to use the same `BinaryReader`. Then you could rewrite this method to look more like this:

```
using (var FS = FileStream(ficsrc, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
using (var BR = new BinaryReader(FS))
{

    var dataformat = (Datatype.SNG)BR.ReadInt32();
    var byteformat = (Byteorder.LittleEndian)BR.ReadInt32();
    var width = BR.ReadInt32();
    var height = BR.ReadInt32();
    ReadImage(ficsrc, width, height, dataformat, byteformat, BR);
}
```